# Uploading File against Lead via REST API

Tags: rest-api, files, contentdocument

I am trying to Upload the File against Lead via REST API.

My understanding is that I need to use ContentDocument and then create Content Document Link against that Lead.

However, I am unable to upload file using Content Document end point and in docos there is no create endpoint (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ContentDocument/get-contentdocument-id)

In simple terms - what would be best way to upload a File against Lead, so it shows itself under Files widget in Salesforce.

Disclaimer: I trailed internet for solution but none seem applicable in my scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly create a `ContentDocument`. Instead, you must upload a [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ContentVersion). The parent `ContentDocument` will be created for you automatically.

To link the file to an sObject, either set the `FirstPublishLocationId` field on the `ContentVersion` to the target record's Id, or query for the `ContentDocumentId` after insertion (it will be populated by the system) and add one or more `ContentDocumentLink` records to connect to sObject records.